# Include Caller # in Auto-generated email

Tags: php, email, forwarding

I am currently using a php script to email me the link of an mp3 recording when a call is made to my Twilio number. How can I include a string that will also provide the caller's phone number in that email?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$to = "EMAILONE"; // Your email address.
$subject = "Message from {$_REQUEST['From']}";
$message = "You have received a voice message from {$_REQUEST['From']}.";
$message .= "To listen to this message, please visit this URL: 
{$_REQUEST['RecordingUrl']}";
$headers = "From: EMAILTWO"; // Who should this email come from?
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

Is it possible to request the caller number and place it in the body of the email?

Thanks!

Comment: This seems like it has more to do with how Twilio works than how to put it into the e-mail. Is there an extra parameter passed to your script, like `$_REQUEST['RecordingUrl']`, `$_REQUEST['From']` etc? For that matter, what's "From" if it's not a phone number?

Comment: Follow what you have now. I.e.: `$phone=$_REQUEST['phone'];` then just use the `$phone` variable inside the message body; `'Yes' : 'No'`?

Comment: According to Twilio's API Documentation, http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request you would be able to access the $_REQUEST['From']; property to get the number, then simply use that as suggested by Fred.

Comment: @thinkMonkey If that's true, then the OP is already doing so - `$subject = "Message from {$_REQUEST['From']}";` and `$message = "You have received a voice message from {$_REQUEST['From']}.";` :|

Comment: yes, that is true. I guess it doesn't seem to make much sense here what the issue is? The Twilio documentation backs up what the OP is doing which leads me to suspect the issue is something else perhaps.